# How does Tensorflow build() work from tf.keras.layers.Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was wondering if anyone knew how the `build()` function works from the `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class under the hood. According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers):

> *build is called when you know the shapes of the input tensors and can
> do the rest of the initialization*

so to me it seems like the class is behaving similar to this:

```
class MyDenseLayer:
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs])

  def __call__(self, input):
    self.build(input.shape) ## build is called here when input shape is known
    return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

I can't imagine `build()` would be called for ever `__call__`, but it is the only place where the input is passed in. Does anyone know how exactly this works under the hood?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Layer.build()` method is typically used to instantiate the weights of the layer. See the [source code for `tf.keras.layers.Dense`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1159-L1190) for an example, and note that the weight and bias tensors are created in that function. The `Layer.build()` method takes an `input_shape` argument, and the shape of the weights and biases often depend on the shape of the input.

The `Layer.call()` method, on the other hand, implements the forward-pass of the layer. You do not want to overwrite `__call__`, because that is implemented in the base class `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. In a custom layer, you should implement `call()`.

`Layer.call()` does not call `Layer.build()`. However, `Layer().__call__()` *does* call it if the layer has not been built yet ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L981-L982)), and that will set an attribute `self.built = True` to prevent `Layer.build()` from being called again. In other words, `Layer.__call__()` only calls `Layer.build()` the first time it is called.

Comment: I see. So it is called on the first forward pass as I had imagined. Thanks for supplying the sources. Much appreciated.

Comment: Is `input_shape` input into build method automatically provided by keras? I dont see `input_shape` being explicitly defined

Comment: the `Layer.build()` method takes an `input_shape` argument